# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

Tags: numpy, typeerror

I meet this question on np.max() fuction, my code is

```
err_qt = np.asarray(err_qt)
err_qt = np.max(err_qt, axis=1)
err_qt = err_qt * 180.0 / np.pi`
```

The err_qt is a matrix and I print it.

```
    [[{'K': array([[682.10083008,   0.        , 239.82280391],
         [  0.        , 683.28820801, 427.01684648],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]]), 'R': array([[-9.93854702e-01, -1.10692268e-01, -2.28596966e-04],
         [ 1.16574434e-03, -8.40159629e-03, -9.99964026e-01],
         [ 1.10686366e-01, -9.93819216e-01,  8.47900486e-03]]), 'T': array([-15.13970906,   1.19332025,  16.90097562]), 'q': array([0., 0., 0., 0.])}
  {'K': array([[682.10083008,   0.        , 239.82280391],
         [  0.        , 683.28820801, 427.01684648],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]]), 'R': array([[-0.88778025, -0.45392103, -0.0761704 ],
         [-0.04630574,  0.2527365 , -0.96642643],
         [ 0.45793232, -0.85444716, -0.24539362]]), 'T': array([-5.09243763, -4.6725806 , 24.14722353]), 'q': array([0., 0., 0., 0.])}]
 [{'K': array([[682.10083008,   0.        , 239.82280391],
         [  0.        , 683.28820801, 427.01684648],
         [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]]), 'R': array([[-9.93854702e-01, -1.10692268e-01, -2.28596966e-04],
         [ 1.16574434e-03, -8.40159629e-03, -9.99964026e-01],
         [ 1.10686366e-01, -9.93819216e-01,  8.47900486e-03]]), 'T': array([-15.13970906,   1.19332025,  16.90097562]), 'q': array([0., 0., 0., 0.])}
...
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What was `err_qt ` before you converted it?

Comment: `np.max` expects a (multidimensional) **numeric** array.  `err_qt` appears to be a 2d array containing `dict` elements.  As the error says, it can't compare `dict` with a `>=` test.  What were you hoping to produce?  What does the `max` of those `dict` mean?  Or were you surprised about the nature of this array?

Comment: Thank for your reply, I'd like to get the max value of each line. The result should be: ([[ 6.82100830e+02,  6.83288208e+02,  4.27016846e+02],
       [ 1.10686366e-01, -8.40159629e-03,  8.47900486e-03]]), ...